# `chrome.browserAction.setIcon()` Is not not persistent after tab reload?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

When extension toolbar icon set via `chrome.pageAction.setIcon()` the icon reverted to default after tab reload (F5)

In the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/) it says:

> If you want to create an icon that isn't always active, use a page
> action instead of a browser action.

Which suggests that the icon supposed to be persistent..
Am I missing something?

Sample extension:

`manifest.json`

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {},
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "test",
   "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
   "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected( tab =>
{
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    path: "data:image/bmp;base64,Qk0eAAAAAAAAABoAAAAMAAAAAQABAAEAGAAAAP8A", //red square icon
    tabId: tab.id
  });
});
```

Comment: The icon **image** is not persistent. The active status of an icon is a different thing.

Comment: Than is there a specific event (most efficient) where I'd need set the icon from?

Comment: I guess you can use chrome.tabs.onUpdated and set the icon when changeInfo.status === 'loading'